# HTML.ActionLink returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, html.actionlink

I have my View page where i have this code:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Admin", new { id = item.Username })%>
```

And here is my controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(String id)
    {
        String x = id;
    }
```

But String x have value "null".Action Result is in Controller Admin so that is not mistake.Also I use item.Username to show results in table and it works fine.

If I try with this in View

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Admin", new { id = item.Username }, null)%>
```

I get error 404.

Does anybody know where is my mistake?

Comment: Have you checked route in Global.asax?

Comment: Yes, everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following overload of ActionLink Helper:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { Controller = "Admin", Action = "Edit", id = item.Username  } )%>
```

That should do the job.

Comment: This code sends me to page ../Admin/Edit/item.Username. Can you tell me how to create code view for this?

Answer (score 0):

Tried Url.Action

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("Edit", "Action", new { id = item.Username }))"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the another overload:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new RouteValueDictionary() {{"id",item.Username}}) %>
```

Click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for more information